# Averaging a very long List[Double] Without getting infinity in Scala

Tags: scala, list, double, bigdata, infinity

I have a very long list of doubles that I need to average but I can't sum them within the double data type so when I go to divide I still get Infinity.

```
 def applyToMap(list: Map[String, List[Map[String, String]]], f: Map[String, String]=>Double): Map[String,Double]={
   val mSLD = list.mapValues(lm=>lm.map(f))
   mSLD.mapValues(ld=> ld.sum/ld.size)

}
```

This leaves me with a Map[String, Double] that are all Key -> Infinity

Comment: Are you sure that you actually overflow `Double`? That's usually somewhat difficult to achieve... You can lose some precision here and there, but it's really difficult to get such a long list of reasonably sized values such that the `sum` overflows to `Infinity`. Are you sure that it's not `f` returning `Infinity`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use fold to compute an average as you go. Rather than doing `sum / size` you should count your way through the items with `n`, and for each one adjust your accumulator with `acc = (acc * n/(n+1)) + (item * 1/(n+1))`

Here’s the general scala code:

```
val average = seq.foldLeft((0.0, 1)) ((acc, i) => ((acc._1 + (i - acc._1) / acc._2), acc._2 + 1))._1
```

Taken from [here](https://damieng.com/blog/2014/12/11/sequence-averages-in-scala).

You’d probably still have precision difficulty if the list is really long, as you’d be dividing by a gradually very large number. To be really safe you should break the list into sublists, and compute the average of averages of the sublists. Make sure the sublists are all the same length though, or do a weighted average based on their size.

Comment: Wouldn't (acc /(n+1) *n) + (item/(n+1)) be safe in regards to reaching infinity (while probably loosing precision)?

Comment: If the list is as long as the question suggests, that's *a lot* of multiplications and divisions that would introduce quite a bit of numeric drift...

Comment: @userunknown Yes it would. The best way to do this depends on how close the numbers are to the minimum or maximum of your data type. I’ve given another option in a comment on your answer.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Indeed. I think that in general the average of averages (with each group average computed via folding as described) approach would probably be best. Working out how best to split it up might be tricky though.

Comment: Maybe searching for the biggest power of two smaller N? Then splitting, until the sum of the sublist can't exceed a reasonable double value? After finding the avg for the largest part, repeat for the rest and keep track on how to weight the rest (and maybe rest of rest ...).

Answer (score 2):

Interested in implementing gandaliters solution, I came up with the following (Since I'm not the well known friend of Doubles, I tried to find an easy to follow numeric sequence with Bytes). First, I generate 10 Bytes in the range of 75..125, to be close to MaxByte, but below for every value, and in average 100, for simple control:

```
val rnd = util.Random   
val is=(1 to 10).map (i => (rnd.nextInt (50)+75).toByte)
// = Vector(99, 122, 99, 105, 102, 104, 122, 99, 87, 114)
```

The 1st algo multiplies before division (which increases the danger to exceed MaxByte), the 2nd divides before multiplication, which leads to rounding errors.

```
def slidingAvg0 (sofar: Byte, x: Byte, cnt: Byte): (Byte, Byte) = {
    val acc : Byte = ((sofar * cnt).toByte / (cnt + 1).toByte + (x/(cnt + 1).toByte).toByte).toByte
    println (acc)
    (acc.toByte, (cnt + 1).toByte)
}

def slidingAvg1 (sofar: Byte, x: Byte, cnt: Byte): (Byte, Byte) = {
    val acc : Byte = (((sofar / (cnt + 1).toByte).toByte * cnt).toByte + (x/(cnt + 1).toByte).toByte).toByte
    println (acc)
    (acc.toByte, (cnt + 1).toByte)
}
```

This is foldLeft in scala:

```
((is.head, 1.toByte) /: is.tail) { case ((sofar, cnt), x) => slidingAvg0 (sofar, x, cnt)}
110
21
41
2
18
32
8
16
0

scala> ((is.head, 1.toByte) /: is.tail) { case ((sofar, cnt), x) => slidingAvg1 (sofar, x, cnt)}
110
105
104
100
97
95
89
81
83
```

Since 10 values is far too less to rely on the average being close to 100, let's see the sum as Int:

```
is.map (_.toInt).sum
res65: Int = 1053
```

The drift is pretty significant (should be 105, is 0/83)

Whether the findings are transferable from Bytes/Int to Doubles is the other question. And I'm not 100% confident, that my braces mirror the evaluation order, but imho, for multiplication/division of same precedence it is left to right.

So the original formulas were:

```
acc = (acc * n/(n+1)) + (item * 1/(n+1))
acc = (acc /(n+1) *n) + (item/(n+1))
```

Comment: This is great! I hadn’t thought about evaluation order - the formula I gave was intended to make clear what was going on rather than to maintain precision. I think if the numbers could be close to the maximum or minimum it would be best to evaluate ‘n/(n+1)’ first, then multiply that by acc (etc.). Of course that number would need to be floating point or it’ll just round to one and everything will be way out.

Comment: @gandaliter: Well, `great` is by far exaggerated. See how the avg decreases in nearly every step? Either such technique needs careful investigation, or better going for the sublists of even length should be considered.

Comment: I meant your analysis rather than the results! I suspect that this is coming out weird as everything is made into a byte at every stage. If scala is just flooring doubles to bytes then no wonder it gets smaller every time.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the OP correctly then the amount of data doesn't seem to be a problem otherwise it wouldn't fit into memory.
So i concentrate on the data types only.

## Summary

My suggestion is to go with `BigDecimal` instead of `Double`.
Especially if you are adding reasonbly high values.
The only significant drawback is the performance and a small amount of cluttered syntax.
Alternatively you must rescale your input upfront but this will degrade precision and requires special care with post processing.

### `Double` breaks at some scale

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val res0 = (Double.MaxValue + 1) == Double.MaxValue
val res1 = Double.MaxValue/10 == Double.MaxValue
val res2 = List.fill(11)(Double.MaxValue/10).sum
val res3 = List.fill(10)(Double.MaxValue/10).sum == Double.MaxValue
val res4 = (List.fill(10)(Double.MaxValue/10).sum + 1) == Double.MaxValue

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = false
res2: Double = Infinity
res3: Boolean = true
res4: Boolean = true
```

Take a look these simple `Double` arithmetics examples in your scala REPL:

1. `Double.MaxValue + 1` will numerically cancel out and nothing is going to be added, thus it is still the same as `Double.MaxValue`
2. `Double.MaxValue/10` behaves as expected and doesn't equal to `Double.MaxValue`
3. Adding `Double.MaxValue/10` for `11` times will produce an overflow to `Infintiy`
4. Adding `Double.MaxValue/10` for `10` times won't break arithmetics and evaluate to `Double.MaxValue` again
5. The summed `Double.MaxValue/10` behaves exactly as the `Double.MaxValue`

### `BigDecimal` works on all scales but is slower

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val res0 = (BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue) + 1) == BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)
val res1 = BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)/10 == BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)
val res2 = List.fill(11)(BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)/10).sum
val res3 = List.fill(10)(BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)/10).sum == BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)
val res4 = (List.fill(10)(BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)/10).sum + 1) == BigDecimal(Double.MaxValue)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res0: Boolean = false
res1: Boolean = false
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 197746244834854727000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
res3: Boolean = true
res4: Boolean = false
```

Now compare these results with the ones above from `Double`.
As you can see everything works as expected.

### Rescaling reduces precision and can be tedious

When working with astronomic or microscopic scales it is likely to happen that numbers will overflow or underflow quickly.
Then it is appropriate to work with other units than the base units to compensate this.
E.g. with km instead of m.
However, then you will have to take special care when multiplying those numbers in formulas.

```
10km * 10km ≠ 100 km^2
```

but rather

```
10,000 m * 10,000 m = 100,000,000 m^2 = 100 Mm^2
```

So keep this in mind.

Another trap is when dealing with very diverse datasets where numbers exist in all kinds of scales and quantities.
When scaling down your input domain you will loose precision and small numbers may be cancelled out.
In some scenarios these numbers don't need to be considered because of their small impact.
However, when these small numbers exist in a high frequency and are ignored all the time you will introduce a large error in the end.

So keep this in mind as well ;)

Hope this helps